# Prove that a formal system is absolutely inconsistent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm using the book An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory: To Truth Through Proof, and it does not have any solutions and barely any examples. I want to understand how to prove that all wff are theorems. Here is one exercise.

> Let $\Lambda$ be a formulation of propositional calculus in which the sole connective are negation and disjunction, the sole rule of inference is Modes Ponens, and with the following axiom schema: $\sim[A\vee B]\vee[B\vee C] $. Prove that $\Lambda$ is absolutely inconsistent.

I know that I need to prove that every wffs is a theorem with only the rule "if $A$ and $\sim A \vee B$  are theorems, B is a theorem" and the above axiom.

Now, let $F$ be a wff, how do I prove it's a theorem, where do I even start?

Comment: You've mis-stated the modus ponens inference rule. IN Andrews's book it is "From $A$ and $\sim{A} \lor B$ to infer $B$" -- it is not about what is a wff!!

Comment: @Peter Ok. I'll rectify that. Thanks

Comment: No. It is not required that the premisses which are inputs to a modus ponens inference are already *theorems* (think about the import of the Deduction Theorem).

Comment: But isn't that what I had earlier, if we have A and ∼A∨B as well formed formula I can deduct B.

Comment: No. What you wrote before was about inferring from the assumptions that $A$ is a wff and $\sim{A} \lor B$ is a wff to the conclusion that $B$ is a wff. What you need is the rule as I gave it. [The assumption that 2 + 3 = 4, and the assumption that "2 + 3 = 4" is a wff are quite different, aren't they? One is false the other can be true.]

Comment: It seems that jiji777 doesn't understand the difference between a formula being a wff and a formula being a theorem.

Comment: @MJD: That is somewhat understandable, since something that is not a wff is usually not called a "formula" at all. There's no such thing as an "ill-formed formula"; there are only sequences of symbols that happen not to be formulas. And so the words "well-formed" mean _exactly nothing_ in this context, except that it is traditional to include them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm can someone please just explain to me how I would go from a random wff to proving it's a theorem.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's find a proof of $X$ where $X$ is a *propositional variable* rather than an arbitrary formula. Afterwards, if want to prove an arbitrary wff $A$, we can take our proof of $X$ and replace every $X$ in that proof with $A$. This works because the system we're working with here has no axioms or inference rules that allow us to do something with a propositional variable that we can't also do with a more complex formula.

We can find a proof of $X$ from the conclusion up by a sort of semi-smart brute force search. Every premise we need must be concluded either by modus ponens or as an instance of the axiom scheme, so whenever we need does *not* have the right shape to be an instance of the axiom, it must be concluded by modus ponens.

This is, for example, the case for the final conclusion $X$, so the last step in the proof must be modus ponens. We then have to prove
$$ {\sim} A \lor X  \qquad\text{and}\qquad A $$
for some $A$ whose structure we're free to choose. The first of these cannot be an axiom no matter which $A$ we choose, so it itself must be concluded by modus ponens. So what we *now* need to prove is
$$ {\sim}B \lor [{\sim}A\lor X] \qquad\qquad B  \qquad\qquad A $$
The first one of these looks promising because it will be an instance of the axiom if only we decide that $B$ is going to be $C\lor{\sim}A$. That leaves us with the following to prove:

$$ C\lor{\sim}A  \qquad\qquad A $$
The first of these again needs to be proved by modus ponens (the negation is in the wrong place and we don't have any rule saying that $\lor$ is commutative), so we need
$$ {\sim}D \lor [C\lor {\sim}A] \qquad\qquad D \qquad\qquad A $$
and the first of *these* becomes an axiom if $D$ is $E\lor C$. That coverts our proof obligations to
$$ E\lor C \qquad\qquad A $$
and these can both be axioms by choosing appopriate unfoldings for $E$, $C$, and $A$, namely

- $A = {\sim}[X\lor X]\lor [X\lor X]$
- $E = {\sim}[X\lor X]$
- $C = X\lor X$

Putting everything together we can write down our proof in standard order:

1. $~{\sim}[X\lor X]\lor [X\lor X] \qquad$ (axiom)
2. $A \qquad$ (1, definition of $A$)
3. $E\lor C \qquad$ (1, definition of $E$ and $C$)
4. ${\sim}[E\lor C]\lor[C\lor {\sim}A] \qquad$ (axiom)
5. $C \lor {\sim}A \qquad$ (3, 4, MP)
6. ${\sim}[C\lor {\sim}A]\lor[{\sim}A\lor X] \qquad$(axiom)
7. ${\sim}A\lor X \qquad$ (5, 6, MP)
8. $X \qquad$ (2, 7, MP)

Comment: Very elegantly done!